# grammatical role of numbers

Tags: parts-of-speech

What's the grammatical role of numbers? For example, in the following sentence:

> That car has two doors.

I mean, "That" is the determiner, "car" is the noun, "has" is the verb. So what's the role of "two"?

Comment: Its function (role) is determiner.

Comment: [*...a **Determiner**, which is a **quasi-adjective***.](https://www.quora.com/Is-two-a-adverb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *That car has two doors*.

The cardinal numbers *one*, *two*, *three*, *four* etc. belong to the class (part of speech) determin**ative** and they function as determin**er** to suitable nouns such as "doors" in your example.